# OpenVPN: Best methods for multiple server authentication

Tags: vpn, openvpn

What is the best way for multiple clients to authenticate to multiple severs? I was thinking a token based system when a token is generated for each client and a custom script is added to verify this. But then that means that users are vulnerable to MITM attacks, as they are not using keys. But generating a client for each server, then having to reset the server and files FOR EACH SERVER is just not acceptable. It also makes revoking very hard. What are the best methods to authenticate multiple users to multiple servers?
Maybe I can use the token based approach and have every user use the same .crt (or is it .pem??), just to confirm the server authenticity to prevent MITM attacks.

Comment: "*But generating a client for each server, then having to reset the server and files FOR EACH SERVER is just not acceptable*" Do you mean generating a certificate for each client?  If so, you do know that you don't need to restart the server after each such generation?  And if so, what is unacceptably hard about  it?  Or do you mean that you need to reset the settings *on each client*, in which case, you do know that you can invoke `openvpn` with a specific config file (one per server) with only a few extra keystrokes?

Comment: @MadHatter I mean that for each server I need to generate a certificate for each client and this looks a bit messy. It also means I have to SSH into potentially hundreds of server just to add one client.

Comment: "*Looks a bit messy*" to whom?  It's the way OpenVPN is designed to work!  Also, why do you have to ssh into hundreds of servers to add one client?  How many OpenVPN servers have you got (and if it's really hundreds, why are they all using *different* CAs)?

Comment: @MadHatter I think it would be a better idea to use certificates as they are well implemented into OpenVPN. Just for clarification, to add a new client if I am using just one CA for every server, I just have to get the main CA and add a client, then I need to update all the server config files? And then to remove a client, remove the client from the CA and update all the config files again? Thanks!

Comment: If you are using one CA for all servers, to add a client you need only mint and sign a new client certificate.  You don't need to touch the servers *at all*, because they will recognise and respect the master CA's stamp on the client cert.  To remove a client, you need to revoke it via your declared CRL; if this is local to all servers, they will each need an updated copy, yes.

Comment: @MadHatter I did more investigation and found that FreeRADIUS was suited to my needs as it means I don't have to roll a custom security framework and it has a lot of support along with scalability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this, is to generate certificates (based on PKI solution).
Then you can have a server certificate for each server and a client certificate also for each client.
The easiest in that case is to use PKCS12 format which embed the complete chain, with CA, sub-ca and private key.

Then to manage revocation, you can use a an OCSP responder, which will take care of responding to revocation status request.

Easy-RSA can take care of that simple PKI.

Comment: What is the difference between using RSA vs. PKI? It looks like I will be using certificates after all due to the safety.

Comment: PKI is the global architecture, and RSA is a kind of key. So via the PKI you generate certificate, which contains private key which could be of RSA kind. I hope this is clearer ?